# Mobile responsive web app that displays two divs individually on screen with next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create mobile responsive web app which has 2 divs side by side. When I switch to mobile browser, I want to display only one div at a time with next button to navigate to second div. Any Idea how it can be done?

I am currently using bootstrap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to do so next and previous on mobile device. you need to use slider script for those div.

Comment: take a look at angular ui-router and try to play with different state, it seems to be the easiest way in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Bootstrap Grid system for this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

In your particular case, use `col-md-6` for each div. It'll display side by side for browser and one after other in mobile.

For displaying one `div` at a time you can use `visible` or `hidden` part of Bootstrap Grid.

You can use something like,

`hidden-xs` (hidden on mobile)

This will hide the div on mobile. To show it again, remove the class.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I did that already but I am stuck with the transition(navigation) between the divs. As I don't want it to be displayed one after other in vertical fashion.

Comment: You could use bootstrap to make both divs the full size of the screen (col-xs-12), set them as 'inline-block', and then set 'whitespace: nowrap' on the parent element. From there you can create classes that will 'translate3d' the div to the appropriate place. Then use JS to add/remove those classes when you click the 'next' button. EDIT: Or just ditch bootstrap and set them to 'position: absolute' and use the classes in the same way described before to change the div's x-coord.